# Graph Connectivity Proof

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose we have an adjacency matrix G representing an n-node graph.  So G[i, j] is 1 if there's an edge from i to j and 0 otherwise.  We can think of each entry as a turned over slip of paper with a 1 or 0 on it.

My text claims the lower bound on the number of times we need to query the matrix to determine if the graph is connected is n * (n-1) / 2.  I'm a bit confused by the proof of this.

Proof: here is the strategy for the adversary: when the algorithm asks us to flip over a slip of paper, we return 0 unless that would force the graph to be disconnected.

**1) This seems to imply that in some cases, if we return a 0, it's impossible for us to add edges later that would lead to a path from u to v.  But surely the graph can still be connected even if we return a 0 above...right?**

Claim: we maintain the invariant that for an y un-asked pair (u, v) the graph revealed so far has no path from u to v

Proof: Suppose there were a path from u to v.  Then we can remove the last edge (u', v') revealed on that path.  We could have answered 0 for that and kept the same connectivity in the graph by having an edge (u, v).  This contradicts the definition of our adversary strategy.

End of proof: Suppose there were an algorithm that finished without examining every slip of paper.  Consider some unasked pair (u, v).  If the algorithm claims the graph is connected, we show all-zeroes for the remaining unasked edges *and this means there is no path from u to v,* so the algorithm is wrong.

**2. Could someone explain the italics?  I'm not seeing the connection...**

On the other hand, if the algorithm says disconnected, we show all-ones for the remaining edges and the algorithm is wrong by the definition of our adversary strategy.

**3. Couldn't the graph still be disconnected even if we show all ones?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose that we have a four-node graph. If the algorithm has queried and gotten "0" answers to 13 and 14, and then it asks about 12, then if the answer is "0", that means that the graph cannot be connected, because 1 is not connected to 2 (there's no direct path, and 1 has no other possible connection).
2. At any given time, you can think of an edge as being a "yes", a "maybe", or a "no". Initially all edges are "maybes". Whenever the algorithm asks about an edge, it becomes a "yes" or a "no". The graph with the yes and maybe edges is the most connected input consistent with observations. The graph with the yes edges only is the least connected input consistent with the observations. The algorithm can return only when these graphs have the same connectivity status.